# Check string for # symbol and the immediately following characters, then colour that string

Tags: php, hash, extract

How can I check a string for a hash tag, and its connected characters?

**Example:** This is my sample string *#example* of what I mean.

****I want to extract this:**** *#example*

Then I want to change the text colour of that found string

Comment: Oh, sorry! It's Friday night - PHP pleasings

Comment: Oh wait - Saturday night

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will surround the hashtag with a span element.

```
$sampleText = 'This is my sample string #example of what I mean. Here is another #test.';
$pattern = '/#[a-zA-Z0-9]*/';
$replacement = '<span class="otherColor">$0</span>';
$updatedText = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement ,$sampleText);
print_r($updatedText);
```

Output:

This is my sample string <span class="otherColor">#example</span> of
what I mean. Here is another <span class="otherColor">#test</span>.

Comment: You are a PHP wizard!